# Multiple aggregate functions in Java 8 Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a class defined like

```
public class TimePeriodCalc {
    private double occupancy;
    private double efficiency;
    private String atDate;
}
```

I would like to perform the following SQL statement using Java 8 Stream API.

```
SELECT atDate, AVG(occupancy), AVG(efficiency)
FROM TimePeriodCalc
GROUP BY atDate
```

I tried :

```
Collection<TimePeriodCalc> collector = result.stream().collect(groupingBy(p -> p.getAtDate(), ....
```

What can be put into the code to select multiple attributes ? I'm thinking of using multiple Collectors but really don't know how to do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do it without a custom `Collector` (not streaming again on the result), you could do it like this. It's a bit dirty, since it is first collecting to `Map<String, List<TimePeriodCalc>>` and then streaming that list and get the average double.

Since you need two averages, they are collected to a `Holder` or a `Pair`, in this case I'm using `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`

```
  Map<String, SimpleEntry<Double, Double>> map = Stream.of(new TimePeriodCalc(12d, 10d, "A"), new TimePeriodCalc(2d, 16d, "A"))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TimePeriodCalc::getAtDate,
                    Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), list -> {
                        double occupancy = list.stream().collect(
                                Collectors.averagingDouble(TimePeriodCalc::getOccupancy));
                        double efficiency = list.stream().collect(
                                Collectors.averagingDouble(TimePeriodCalc::getEfficiency));
                        return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(occupancy, efficiency);
                    })));

    System.out.println(map);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way with a custom collector. It only needs one pass, but it's not very easy, especially because of generics...

If you have this method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@SafeVarargs
static <T, A, C extends Collector<T, A, Double>> Collector<T, ?, List<Double>>
averagingManyDoubles(ToDoubleFunction<? super T>... extractors) {

    List<C> collectors = Arrays.stream(extractors)
        .map(extractor -> (C) Collectors.averagingDouble(extractor))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    class Acc {
        List<A> averages = collectors.stream()
            .map(c -> c.supplier().get())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        void add(T elem) {
            IntStream.range(0, extractors.length).forEach(i ->
                collectors.get(i).accumulator().accept(averages.get(i), elem));
        }

        Acc merge(Acc another) {
            IntStream.range(0, extractors.length).forEach(i ->
                averages.set(i, collectors.get(i).combiner()
                    .apply(averages.get(i), another.averages.get(i))));
            return this;
        }

        List<Double> finish() {
            return IntStream.range(0, extractors.length)
                .mapToObj(i -> collectors.get(i).finisher().apply(averages.get(i)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }
    return Collector.of(Acc::new, Acc::add, Acc::merge, Acc::finish);
}
```

This receives an array of functions that will extract `double` values from each element of the stream. These extractors are converted to `Collectors.averagingDouble` collectors and then the local `Acc` class is created with the mutable structures that are used to accumulate the averages for each collector. Then, the accumulator function forwards to each accumulator, and so with the combiner and finisher functions.

Usage is as follows:

```
Map<String, List<Double>> averages = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        TimePeriodCalc::getAtDate,
        averagingManyDoubles(
            TimePeriodCalc::getOccupancy,
            TimePeriodCalc::getEfficiency)));
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your `TimePeriodCalc` class has all the necessary getters, this should get you the list you want:

```
List<TimePeriodCalc> result = new ArrayList<>(
    list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TimePeriodCalc::getAtDate, 
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), TimePeriodCalc::avgTimePeriodCalc)))
    .values()
);
```

Where `TimePeriodCalc.avgTimePeriodCalc` is this method in the `TimePeriodCalc` class:

```
public static TimePeriodCalc avgTimePeriodCalc(List<TimePeriodCalc> list){
    return new TimePeriodCalc(
            list.stream().collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(TimePeriodCalc::getOccupancy)),
            list.stream().collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(TimePeriodCalc::getEfficiency)),
            list.get(0).getAtDate()
            );
}
```

---

The above can be combined into this monstrosity:

```
List<TimePeriodCalc> result = new ArrayList<>(
    list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TimePeriodCalc::getAtDate, 
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.toList(), a -> {
                return new TimePeriodCalc(
                        a.stream().collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(TimePeriodCalc::getOccupancy)),
                        a.stream().collect(Collectors.averagingDouble(TimePeriodCalc::getEfficiency)),
                        a.get(0).getAtDate()
                        );
            }
        )))
    .values());
```

With input:

```
List<TimePeriodCalc> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new TimePeriodCalc(10,10,"a"));
list.add(new TimePeriodCalc(10,10,"b"));
list.add(new TimePeriodCalc(10,10,"c"));
list.add(new TimePeriodCalc(5,5,"a"));
list.add(new TimePeriodCalc(0,0,"b"));
```

This would give:

```
TimePeriodCalc [occupancy=7.5, efficiency=7.5, atDate=a]
TimePeriodCalc [occupancy=5.0, efficiency=5.0, atDate=b]
TimePeriodCalc [occupancy=10.0, efficiency=10.0, atDate=c]
```

Comment: the diff of doing the average manually is that the `Kahan summation` is used internally inside `averagingDouble`, making the result a more correct one

Comment: yes, but then I already did the same thing. You can leave the answer of course, may be someone will find it useful.

Comment: Hadn't even noticed you already posted an answer ...Ah well, at least the outcome of my answer is somewhat easier to use.

Comment: Hi Robin, When I tried :

`List<TimePeriodCalc> result = new ArrayList<>(
    list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TimePeriodCalc::getAtDate, 
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), a -> TimePeriodCalc::avgTimePeriodCalc)))
    .values()
);`

I got Object is not a functional interface. But the a -> return ... works well.
Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @KhaNguyễn Sorry, seems like you found a typo there. Will be fixed in a few seconds

Answer (score 0):

You can chain multiple attributes like this:

```
Collection<TimePeriodCalc> collector = result.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getAtDate(), Collectors.averagingInt(p -> p.getOccupancy())));
```

If you want more, you get the idea.

Comment: How does this get the average of the `occupancy` and `efficiency` fields?

Comment: ok, I was assuming `getOccupancy()` returns the average already

Comment: Looks like a simple getter to me

Comment: Edited so it doesn't ;)

Comment: Hi @Tavo, thank for helping. But when I try to apply more than one arg functions like :

    `result.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getAtDate(), Collectors.averagingInt(p -> p.getOccupancy()), Collectors.averagingInt(p -> p.getEfficiency())))`

I get the error : no suitable method found. I assume that collect method does not accept multiple Collectors. Thank you.

Comment: This  doesn't address "Multiple aggregate functions" part of the question title. I think @Eugene's answer is the one which answers the question best

Comment: @KhaNguyễn yes, because there is a typo. When you do `p->p.getOccupancy())`, you have an extra bracket there. I've seen that @Eugene's answer has already sorted it out, so no need to check it out now.
@Dark, how doesn't it address it? There is one collector for the date and a second one for the occupancy. The third is just a matter of adding one more.