# Transform Java Stream and return reduced values both

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Assuming I consume a Stream of entities from a source which I do not want to materialize, and I want to both transform the elements, and return some globally reduced value, what is the idiomatic way with java(8)?

This is essentially trying to perform both a `reduce()` and a `collect()`.

Example:

```java
class Person {
    public String firstname,
    public String lastname,
    public int age;
}

class TeamSummary {
    public List<String> fullnames, // firstname and lastname of all
    public Person oldest
}

public TeamSummary getSummary(Stream<Person> personStream) {
   final TeamSummary summary = new Summary();
   summary.fullnames = personStream
       .peek(p -> if (summary.getOldest() == null || summary.getOldest.age < p.age) {
           summary.oldest = p;
       })
       .map(p -> p.firstname + ' ' + p.lastname)
       .collect(toList());
   return summary;
}
```

It looks ugly to interact with a variable outside the stream inside the peek method, but what good alternatives are there, it seems I need to combine `collect()` and `reduce()`.

It get's worse if I want to get a reduced value from the whole stream (like average age), and a filtered list (like Persons above 18 years). It also get's worse if TeamSummary is an immutable class, and additional mutable variables are required.

In such cases it is more idiomatic to use a while loop on stream.iterator() to avoid coupling of stream methods and variables? Or is it natural to use reduce to a tuple like (oldest, accumulated).

I am aware this question is a matter of opinion unless there is an obvious way (like a special collector) that solves this elegantly.

Comment: Why don't you just use `reduce() `? Or a custom collector?

Comment: Because when I try doing those things, the code become much more complicated to write and read than the one I have written so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want to reduce your collection to a single value? That's where `Collectors.reducing` comes into play (Alternative: You could use `Stream.reduce` but with other modifications). Furthermore, you want to aggregate your values in some way and also have the perfect accumulator: `TeamSummary`.

Now, in the below code I made the foollowing adjustments:

- Team Summary has the merge/identity function required for reduce, as it serves as the accumulator
- I use a [Null Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) instead of `null` for a non-existing person, which makes the code much more readable without null checks (NPE during converter being one of the problems). Have you thought about your output if the stream is empty?
- I added a `Person` constructor for my own convenience. But consider using getters and final fields (even if you think getters and the whole fake encapsulation are boilerplate: You can use method references, e.g. to pass to a comparator, but not field references)

Here is the code:

```
static class Person {
    public String firstname;
    public String lastname;
    public int age;

    public Person(String firstname, String lastname, int age) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public static Person getNullObjectYoung() {
        return new Person("", "", 0);
    }
}

static class TeamSummary {
    public List<String> fullnames;
    public Person oldest;

    public static TeamSummary merge(TeamSummary lhs, TeamSummary rhs) {
        TeamSummary result = new TeamSummary();
        result.fullnames = new ArrayList<>();
        result.fullnames.addAll(lhs.fullnames);
        result.fullnames.addAll(rhs.fullnames);
        result.oldest = Comparator.<Person, Integer>comparing(p -> p.age).reversed()
                .compare(lhs.oldest, rhs.oldest) < 0
                ? lhs.oldest
                : rhs.oldest;
        return result;
    }

    public static TeamSummary of(Person person) {
        TeamSummary result = new TeamSummary();
        result.fullnames = new ArrayList<>();
        result.fullnames.add(person.firstname + " " + person.lastname);
        result.oldest = person;
        return result;
    }

    public static TeamSummary identity() {
        TeamSummary result = new TeamSummary();
        result.fullnames = new ArrayList<>();
        result.oldest = Person.getNullObjectYoung();
        return result;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {        
    Stream<Person> personStream = Arrays.asList(
            new Person("Tom", "T", 32),
            new Person("Bob", "B", 40))
            .stream();

    TeamSummary result = personStream.collect(
            Collectors.reducing(
                    TeamSummary.identity(),
                    TeamSummary::of,
                    TeamSummary::merge
            ));
    System.out.println(result.fullnames + " " + result.oldest.age);

}
```

Note: You asked for a java 8 version. Maybe in java 12, you could also use `Collectors.teeing`, since you basically want to do two different reductions at the same time (for which we can currently leverage the accumulator).

---

Edit: Also added a solution for `Stream.reduce`, which requires a BiFunction (summary, person) -> person:

```
static class TeamSummary {

    ...

    public TeamSummary include(final Person person) {
        final TeamSummary result = new TeamSummary();
        result.fullnames = new ArrayList<>(fullnames);
        result.fullnames.add(person.firstname + " " + person.lastname);
        result.oldest = Comparator.<Person, Integer> comparing(p -> p.age).reversed()
                .compare(oldest, person) < 0
                        ? oldest
                        : person;
        return result;
    }
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    ...

    final TeamSummary reduced = personStream.reduce(
            TeamSummary.identity(),
            TeamSummary::include,
            TeamSummary::merge);
}
```

Comment: A solution using teeing should see several upvotes here, though I asked for Java8 indeed.

Comment: For java 8, I usually either use `Collectors.reducing` with a proper accumulator (as shown above) or use two different collectors (if iterating the source collection twice is not a problem).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the requirements such as - `Stream` as input and inferring the complete list of names in the output of `teamSummary`. You can perform the operation `map`ping the person and its name details to an entry and then `reduce` them further such as :

```
return personStream
        .map(p -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(p, Collections.singletonList(p.getFirstname() + ' ' + p.getLastname())))
        .reduce((entry1, entry2) -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(entry1.getKey().getAge() >= entry2.getKey().getAge() ?
                entry1.getKey() : entry2.getKey(), Stream.of(entry1.getValue(), entry2.getValue()).flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList())))
        .map(entry -> new TeamSummary(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
        .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
```

For a readable and simplified approach though I would rather suggest passing on the collection and working with multiple stream operations here to construct the `TeamSummary` as :

```
public TeamSummary getSummary(List<Person> people) {
    List<String> fullNames = people.stream()
            .map(p -> p.getFirstname() + ' ' + p.getLastname())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    Person oldestPerson = people.stream()
            .reduce(BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge)))
            .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
    return new TeamSummary(oldestPerson, fullNames);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is a correct implementation, but is is neither very readable nor very resource-friendly, so I would not consider it idiomatic (unless you get a lot of upvotes maybe).

Comment: @tkruse I would agree with you that the first approach is not idiomatic(nevermind the votes) and brings in rather the complexity in terms of readability and maintenance. Just that passing over a collection and computing the varied results in different operations would make much sense IMHO.

Comment: But the assumption is that I do not want to materialize the list. You can imagine that it is too big for memory by adding more fields to Person. If you change the answer to  pass over all results in a loop without changing the stream as method input, I could accept the answer.

Comment: @tkruse to what I could think of, passing on the stream, the first option is the way to go, since one cannot consume the stream more than once. Or rather pass on a `Supplier` of the `Stream` to consume it multiple times. Also, the requirement of collecting the list of all the names while storing only the oldest in the summary might be achieved by using a `for` loop but they still don't seem to make much sense together IMHO. Seems like the actual problem is the cause for which you're trying to optimize using `Stream` as a parameter.

Comment: consuming the same stream twice and looping again is very bad, imagine this is a long running operation with many rows. I know doing both together is difficult, but if this war an iterator everyone would just use a while loop without thinking twice, so I look for a similarly simple solution for stream (which is very similar to iterator). You can answer by calling stream.iterator() in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you'd use `Collectors.reducing()` when you can `stream.reduce()` directly?

```
BinaryOperator<Player> older = (p1, p2) -> 
    Comparator.comparing(Player::getAge) > 0 
        ? p1 : p2;
TeamSummary summary = stream.reduce(
    TeamSummary::new, // identity
    // accumulator
    (ts, player) -> {
        ts.addFullnames(String.format("%s %s", player.firstName, player.lastName));
        ts.setOldest(older.apply(ts.getOldest(), player));
    }
    // combiner
    (ts1, ts2) -> {
        // we can safely modify the given summaries, they were all created while reducing
        ts1.setOldest(Math.max(ts1.getOldest(), ts2.getOldest()));
        ts1.addFullnames(ts2.getFullnames().toArray());
        return ts1;
    });
```

`TeamSummary` would then look like this:

```
class TeamSummary {
    private int oldest; 
    public Player getOldest() { return oldest; }
    public void setOldest(Player newOldest) { oldest = newOldest; }

    private List<String> fullnames();
    public List<String> getFullnames() { return Collections.unmodifiableList(fullnames); }

    public void addFullnames(String... names) {
        fullnames.addAll(Arrays.asList(names));
    }
}
```

**Alternative**

You could also extend `TeamSummary` with something like `addPlayer(Player p)` and `merge()` to allow it to maintain its consistency:

```
class TeamSummary {

    @Getter
    private int oldest;
    @Getter
    private List<String> fullnames = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addPlayer(Player p) {
        fullnames.add(String.format("%s %s", p.getFirstname(), p.getLastname()));
        oldest = olderPlayer(oldest, p);
    }
    public TeamSummary merge(TeamSummary other) {
        older = olderPlayer(oldest, other.oldest)
        fullnames.addAll(other.fullnames);
        return this;
    }

    final static Comparator<Player> BY_AGE = Comparator.comparing(Player::getAge);
    private static Player olderPlayer(Player p1, Player p2) {
        return BY_AGE.compare(p1, p2) > 0 ? p1 : p2;
    }
}
```

which would make the reduction

```
stream.reduce(
    TeamSummary::new,
    TeamSummary::addPlayer,
    TeamSummary::merge
);
```

Comment: for completeness sake, you could add the modified TeamSummary class

Comment: @tkruse added class and alternative.

Comment: Note that you are using only the age, not the whole `Person` in your `TeamSummary` (thus, with default value of 0, using that as the default value for the identity). Maybe you want to make that explicit by assigning `= 0`, in case the requirement changes to e.g. save the _youngest_ age.

Comment: @sfiss I missed the fact that `oldest` referred to the actual player in the OP. Adjusted my code.

Comment: Make sure you test it and don't run into an NPE during your comparator (that's the reason why I included the NullObject in my answer). Just looking at `TeamSummary::new`, I would assume you get the runtime exception.